# name is not defined in ROS2 python launch file

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi. Sorry for all mistakes, English is not my native language. I've come from ROS1 and very familiar with ROS2 python launch system so, maybe, for anybody this problem will be obvious, but, unfortunately, not for me. I have the following launch file:

```
import os
import sys
import xacro

import launch
import launch_ros.actions
from launch.substitutions import LaunchConfiguration
from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory
from launch.substitutions import PythonExpression

xacro_path = os.path.join(get_package_share_directory('minicar_description'), 'urdf', 'minicar.xacro')
xacro_doc = xacro.parse(open(xacro_path, 'r'))
xacro.process_doc(xacro_doc)
robot_description = xacro_doc.toxml()

def generate_launch_description():
    target = LaunchConfiguration("target", default='jetson')
    use_sim_time = LaunchConfiguration('use_sim_time', default='true')
    minicar_cartographer_prefix = get_package_share_directory('minicar_slam')
    cartographer_config_dir = LaunchConfiguration('cartographer_config_dir', default=os.path.join(
                                                minicar_cartographer_prefix, 'config'))
    configuration_basename = PythonExpression(["'cartographer_jetson.lua' if ", target, "==jetson else 'cartographer_host.lua'"])

    LaunchConfiguration('configuration_basename',default=configuration_basename)

    resolution = LaunchConfiguration('resolution', default='0.05')
    ##publish_period_sec = LaunchConfiguration('publish_period_sec', default='1.0')

    ##rviz_config_dir = os.path.join(get_package_share_directory('turtlebot3_cartographer'), 'rviz', 'tb3_cartographer.rviz')

    ld = launch.LaunchDescription([
        launch.actions.DeclareLaunchArgument(
            'cartographer_config_dir',
            default_value=cartographer_config_dir
        ),
        launch.actions.DeclareLaunchArgument(
            'configuration_basename',
            default_value=configuration_basename
        ),
        launch.actions.DeclareLaunchArgument(
            'use_sim_time',
            default_value=use_sim_time
        ),
        launch.actions.DeclareLaunchArgument(
            'target',
            default_value=target
        ),
        launch.actions.DeclareLaunchArgument(
            name='config',
            default_value=PythonExpression(["'cartographer_jetson.lua' if ", target, "==jetson else 'cartographer_host.lua'"])
        ),
        launch.actions.DeclareLaunchArgument(
            name='odom',
            #default_value="$(var '/rs_t265/odom/sample' if (target == 'jetson') else '/minicar/controller/odom')"
            default_value=PythonExpression(["'/rs_t265/odom/sample' if ",target, "==jetson else '/minicar/controller/odom'"])
        ),
        launch.actions.DeclareLaunchArgument(
            name='scan',
            default_value='/minicar/rplidar/scan'
        ),
        launch.actions.DeclareLaunchArgument(
            name='map',
            default_value='none'
        ),
        launch.actions.DeclareLaunchArgument(
            name='bag',
            default_value='none'
        ),
        launch_ros.actions.Node(
            package='cartographer_ros',
            executable='cartographer_node',
            name='cartographer_node',
            output='screen',
            parameters=[
                {
                    'robot_description': robot_description
                }
            ],
            condition=launch.conditions.IfCondition("$(var map == 'none')")
        ),
        launch_ros.actions.Node(
            package='cartographer_ros',
            executable='cartographer_node',
            name='cartographer_node',
            output='screen',
            parameters=[
                {
                    'robot_description': robot_description
                }
            ],
            arguments=[
                '-configuration_directory', cartographer_config_dir,
                '-configuration_basename', configuration_basename
            ],
            condition=launch.conditions.IfCondition("$(var map != 'none')")
        ),
        launch_ros.actions.Node(
            package='robot_state_publisher',
            executable='robot_state_publisher',
            name='robot_state_publisher',
            parameters=[
                {
                    'use_sim_time': use_sim_time,
                    'robot_description': robot_description
                }
            ],
            arguments=[
                '-configuration_directory', cartographer_config_dir,
                '-configuration_basename', configuration_basename
            ],
            condition=launch.conditions.IfCondition(PythonExpression(["$(var bag != 'none')"]))
        ),
        launch_ros.actions.Node(
            package='rosbag2',
            executable='play',
            name='playbag',
            parameters=[
                {
                    
                    'robot_description': robot_description

                }
            ],
            condition=launch.conditions.IfCondition(PythonExpression(["$(var bag != 'none')"]))
        ),
        launch_ros.actions.Node(
            package='cartographer_ros',
            executable='occupancy_grid_node',
            name='cartographer_occupancy_grid_node',
            arguments=[
                'resolution', resolution
            ],
            parameters=[
                {
                    'robot_description': robot_description
                }
            ]
        )
    ])
    return ld


if __name__ == '__main__':
    generate_launch_description()
```

That generate this error:

```
[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /home/mikita/.ros/log/2022-11-17-04-43-30-782618-ubuntu-104998
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-2' coro=<LaunchService._process_one_event() done, defined at /opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/launch/launch_service.py:226> exception=NameError("name 'jetson' is not defined")>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/launch/launch_service.py", line 228, in _process_one_event
    await self.__process_event(next_event)
File "/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/launch/launch_service.py", line 248, in __process_event
    visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures(entity, self.__context))
File "/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/launch/utilities/visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures_impl.py", line 45, in visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures
    futures_to_return += visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures(sub_entity, context)
File "/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/launch/utilities/visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures_impl.py", line 45, in visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures
    futures_to_return += visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures(sub_entity, context)
File "/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/launch/utilities/visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures_impl.py", line 45, in visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures
    futures_to_return += visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures(sub_entity, context)
[Previous line repeated 1 more time]
File "/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/launch/utilities/visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures_impl.py", line 38, in visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures
    sub_entities = entity.visit(context)
File "/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/launch/action.py", line 108, in visit
    return self.execute(context)
File "/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/launch/actions/declare_launch_argument.py", line 184, in execute
    perform_substitutions(context, self.default_value)
File "/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/launch/utilities/perform_substitutions_impl.py", line 26, in perform_substitutions
    return ''.join([context.perform_substitution(sub) for sub in subs])
File "/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/launch/utilities/perform_substitutions_impl.py", line 26, in <listcomp>
    return ''.join([context.perform_substitution(sub) for sub in subs])
File "/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/launch/launch_context.py", line 219, in perform_substitution
    return substitution.perform(self)
File "/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/launch/substitutions/python_expression.py", line 72, in perform
    return str(eval(perform_substitutions(context, self.expression), {}, math.__dict__))
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'jetson' is not defined
```

I'm trying to follow [this](https://github.com/chargerKong/learning_ros2_launch_by_example/blob/main/docs/How%20to%20use%20pythonexpression.md) and [this](https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Tutorials/Intermediate/Launch/Using-Substitutions.html#substitutions-example-launch-file) examples of IfCondition and PythonExpression usage, but, apparently, I'm missing something. Appreciate any help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/409512/name-is-not-defined-in-ros2-python-launch-file/) by [Edvard](https://answers.ros.org/users/119522/edvard/) on ROS Answers with karma: 95 on 2022-11-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2022-11-17**:
It would be appreciated if you can minimize the code to review to [MRE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_reproducible_example) - if possible, with one argument and one node only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can you add a `' '` around  `jetson` here and try again?

`default_value=PythonExpression(["'/rs_t265/odom/sample' if ",target, "=='jetson' else '/minicar/controller/odom'"])`

You are comparing strings, without `' '` around it Python treats it like a variable name

---

Originally posted by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) with karma: 3064 on 2022-11-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Edvard](https://answers.ros.org/users/119522/edvard/) on 2022-11-18**:
Thank you for your help. I followed your suggestion and also changed LaunchConfiguration for target like this:

```
target = LaunchConfiguration("target", default="'jetson'")
```

and problem solved.